# Solve a 2-dimensional optimal control problem via Riccati nonlinear equation

Tags: oc.optimization-and-control, nonlinear-optimization

> Consider the 2-dimensional optimal control problem of the LQR kind
>   $$
>     \min_u \int_0^\infty (x^T Q x + u^TRu) \, dt \quad\text{such that}\quad \begin{cases}\dot x(t) = Ax(t)+Bu(t) \\ x(0) = \begin{pmatrix}1\\-1\end{pmatrix}\end{cases}
> $$
>   with $x=\begin{pmatrix}x_1 \\ x_2\end{pmatrix}$, $u=\begin{pmatrix}u_1\\u_2\end{pmatrix}$, $Q=B=I$ (identity), $R=\gamma I$, $A=\begin{pmatrix}-\alpha & \alpha\\\beta & -\beta\end{pmatrix}$, $\alpha>\beta>0$ and $\gamma>0$.
>
> Solve it using the stationary Riccati equation
>   $$
>     0 = Q+A^TS+SA-SBR^{-1}BS,\quad \text{with}\quad S=\begin{pmatrix}s_1 & s_2 \\ s_2 & s_3\end{pmatrix}.
> $$

In order to find $x$ and $u$ we have to combine the equation for $\dot x$ with the equation for the optimal control $u = -R^{-1}B^TSx = -\frac1\gamma Sx$. So, firstly, we have to find the expression for $S$.

The Riccati equation is simplified as
$$
   0 = I+A^TS+SA-\frac1\gamma S^2
$$
which is equivalent to the following nonlinear system
    $$
\begin{cases}
    -\dfrac{s_1^2}{\gamma}-2\alpha s_1  -\dfrac{s_2^2}{\gamma}+2\beta s_2+1=0\\
    \alpha s_1 - \alpha s_2 - \beta s_2 + \beta s_3 - \dfrac{s_1s_2}{\gamma}-\dfrac{s_2s_3}{\gamma}=0\\
    -\dfrac{s_2^2}{\gamma}+2\alpha s_2 - \dfrac{s_3^2}{\gamma} - 2\beta s_3+1 = 0
\end{cases}
$$

How to solve such a non-linear system to find expressions for $s_1, s_2$ and $s_3$? I think there is a fast way to solve either the system or directly the Riccati equation in matrix form, but I don't know how.

The solutions provided by Matlab, using the code below, are so long that it let me think is not the correct way to solve the problem

```
syms x y z a b g
eqn1 = 0 == -x^2/g-2*a*x-y^2/g+2*b*y+1;
eqn2 = 0 == a*x-a*y-b*y+b*z-x*y/g-y*z/g;
eqn3 = 0 == -y^2/g+2*a*y-z^2/g-2*b*z+1;
[x,y,z] = solve([eqn1, eqn2, eqn3], [x, y, z])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution of a Riccati equation can be found by determining the eigenvectors of the Hamiltonian; see e.g. [here on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebraic_Riccati_equation#Solution). This is your best hope for a closed-form symbolic solution, in my view. In your case, the Hamiltonian is
[
\begin{bmatrix}
-\alpha & \alpha & -\gamma^{-1} & 0\\
\beta & -\beta & 0 & -\gamma^{-1}\\
-1 & 0 & \alpha & -\beta\\
0 & -1 & -\alpha & \beta
\end{bmatrix}.
]
I don't see immediately how to diagonalize it, but maybe someone here has a more trained eye than me.

Comment: Thanks, I did not know about this method. Calling `H` the Hamiltonian matrix, the diagonalization can be performed in matlab with `[V,D] = eig(H)`, where `V` is the matrix of eigenvectors and `D` the diagonal matrix of eigenvalues. However, also in this case the values computed are very long.

Comment: Using `V` and `D`, how can I construct the matrices $U_1$ and $U_2$ cited in the page you linked? In particular, see https://i.imgur.com/WbfKw7I.png

Comment: $\begin{bmatrix}U_1 \\ U_2\end{bmatrix}\in\mathbb{C}^{2n\times n}$ ($n=2$ in your case) is obtained by concatenating horizontally the $n$ eigenvectors that are associated to eigenvalues in the left half-plane. In (succinct) Matlab, `U = V(:, real(diag(D)) < 0)`. If you have eigenvalues with real part zero, then it is trickier (but that shouldn't happen in your case).

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. Problem is that the command `real(diag(D))` doesn't work if `D` contains symbolic variables, does it? Anyway, I computed the eigenvalues for several values of the parameters, respecting the constraints $\alpha>\beta>0$ and $\gamma>0$. If parameters are smaller than 0.5, then eigenvalues are likely complex numbers, otherwise they are real numbers, but in all cases two eigenvalues have negative real parts and the other two have non-negative real parts. In one case two eigenvalues were 0. If all eigenvalues are real, it is easy to compute `U` and `S=U2*inv(U1)`.

Comment: I don't understand why $\begin{bmatrix}U_1 \\ U_2\end{bmatrix}$ is a complex valued matrix. On wiki page it is written "Since $H$ is Hamiltonian, if it does not have any eigenvalues on the imaginary axis, then exactly half of its eigenvalues have a negative real part.". Doesn't this mean that if $H$ does not have any complex eigenvalue then half of its eigenvalues are negative? They are assuming that eigenvalues are not complex. so why they talk about "negative real part"?

Comment: If the eigenvalues are complex, $U$ (as we constructed it) is complex. If the eigenvalues are real, $U$ is real. That wiki page is assuming that $H$ may have *complex* eigenvalues, but not *imaginary* eigenvalues (that's two different things).

Comment: Ah ok thanks, so $H$ may have complex eigenvalues, but their real parts have to be different from 0, otherwise they are imaginary.

Comment: Assume we have found the expression for $S$, in order to find $x(t)$ I think we have to plug the expression for $S$ inside the optimal control $u(t) = -R^{-1}B^TSx(t)$, and then plug it inside $\dot x(t) = Ax(t)+u(t)$, compute the integral and apply the initial condition $x(0)$, right?

Comment: Depending what you mean by "solve the problem", yes, you might have to do it.

Comment: I mean to solve the minimization problem, i.e. find $x(t)$ and $u(t)$ such that the initial integral attains the minimum value in such a way that initial condition and eq for $\dot x$ hold

Comment: A user found a way (https://mathoverflow.net/questions/355910/spectral-decomposition-of-a-4-times4-real-nonsymmetric-matrix-with-unknown-ele/) to diagonalize the Hamiltonian matrix, do you think it is possible to solve the problem (i.e. find the expression for $x(t)$) using it? I'm trying to compute the inverse of $U_1$ but I cannot find a handy way to do it. Using the user's notation $U_1 = \begin{bmatrix}
-\left(B^{\rm{T}}-\lambda_1{\rm{I}_2}\right)\mathbf{w}_{1r} &
-\left(B^{\rm{T}}-\lambda_2{\rm{I}_2}\right)\mathbf{w}_{2r}
\end{bmatrix}$